# IE not loading specific Stylesheet

Tags: css, internet-explorer

As you can see [on this live demo](http://germanalvarez.net/5/laboratory.html), I have a website with two stylesheets, one for our beloved IE and another one for the normal browsers, set like this on its header:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="stylelab.css">
<!--[if IE]>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="ie_stylelab.css" />
<![endif]-->
```

Even though I have checked many times its spelling, it seems correct but if you open the link from IE (IE v11, in my case), normal Stylesheet is loaded instead IE one.

To check easily if the other CSS is loaded, in theory, when opening the link from any IE and executing the menu (bottom right button), it has blue background.

What is missing here?

IE stylesheet has the entire normal stylesheed PLUS the additional properties needed for it to work, maybe this is wrong and shoul only have the additional properties..?

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/hh801214(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: I'm really beginning to feel that using alternate style sheets for the benefit of one particular browser is a bad practice.  It seems far safer to me to code you CSS better.

Comment: @j08691 Please respond with an Answer, with the appropriate text copied from the source.

Comment: @JoeFrambach I am waiting for the user to answert this. If not it will be answeered and ticked by myself.

Comment: @durbnpoisn, in my case, IE does not accept opacities on pseudoelements, so I must set opacity:inherit to each one. This makes it work on IE but not on any other browser. I widsh I could have a single one but find no other option.. Here's related question with opacity problem: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25746286/opacity-animations-not-working-on-ie

Comment: http://www.paulirish.com/2008/conditional-stylesheets-vs-css-hacks-answer-neither/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> **Conditional comments are no longer supported**
>
> Support for conditional comments has been removed in Internet Explorer
>   10 standards and quirks modes for improved interoperability and
>   compliance with HTML5. This means that Conditional Comments are now
>   treated as regular comments, just like in other browsers. This change
>   can impact pages written exclusively for Windows Internet Explorer or
>   pages that use browser sniffing to alter their behavior in Internet
>   Explorer.

See: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/hh801214(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: Ill tick in 8 minutes.

Answer (score 1):

IE stopped support for conditional comments as of IE10.
At this point a better solution is to target CSS based on features rather than vendors/browsers. Tools like modernizr can really help you with this.

Comment: I'll have a look at Modernizr, I am not an expert on it but I cant believe how could I start thinking about several CSS without having seen it first. Thank you.